# Comment section for each thread not loading comments properly

Tags: php, sql

I'm building a website where people can leave comments on each event created by me. Each event has its own page eg. `showthread.php?t=1`, `showthread.php?t=2` and so on..

I managed to create a comment section for each event but I got a problem with loading comment for each event. I used `$_SESSION['id']` to pass the `$_GET['t']` value to another php script

My code is like this:

**showthread.php**

```
$id=$_GET['t'];
$_SESSION['id']=$id;
```

**main_function.php**

```
$thread=$_SESSION["id"];
```

`SELECT * FROM comment WHERE thread='$thread' ORDER BY timestamp DESC`,
these codes are working fine but I need to refresh the page in order to load the right comment for each thread, is there a way for me to load it properly without refreshing each time I load an event? thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use AJAX to pull the latest data without reloading the whole page.

Comment: haven't tried AJAX before. but can you give me atleast a guide to get me started?

Comment: can i still use AJAX's get even if my `main_function.php` has multiple select queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AJAX is javascript used to make requests to the server. You can use it to change your page without refreshing.

[Learn more here.](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp)

An example of what it looks like:

```
//create the request object
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 

//activates when you hear back from the server
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() { 
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
       //xhttp.responseText is filled with what we get back from the server
       document.getElementById("my-element-thing").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
    }
};

//Type of request, url you're sending to, asyncronous
xhttp.open("GET", "www.google.com?p=myparam", true);

//Send your request to the server
xhttp.send();
```

**Edit:** The idea is you would also build a PHP page to accept this request. PHP would analyze it and then echo a response. Be sure that the PHP only contains what you want and nothing else (no  tags etc).

Comment: but `main_function.php` is the php script for all functions of my whole website (eg. login, forgot password, signup, etc.) and `showthread.php` works like my UI for the comment section. plus i dont really know how to use AJAX but ill try to learn about it.

Comment: Well you can use main_function.php to accept the requests so long as you can work with what it sends back.

Comment: For example if your request is like `main_function.php?juice=applejuice` then you could have some PHP like `if(isset($_GET['juice'])){ - - - do stuff - - -}`

Comment: is it possible to send a request without clicking a button?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use javascript AJAX?
https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp